# Generate one of many ways of distributing toys among children

Tags: algorithm, random, set-theory

- There are N children and a finite set T of distinguishable toys;
- Each child *likes* a particular subset T<sub>i</sub> of all toys;
- Each child needs to *own* an exact number t<sub>i</sub> <= |T<sub>i</sub>| of toys, but only from the toys that child likes;
- Some toys are liked by more than one child.
- A toy can't be owned by multiple children

.

There are possibly many ways to satisfy each child's need for toys.

**Problem:** Given N, {T<sub>i</sub>}, {t<sub>i</sub>} and a seeded RNG, from all possible configurations of toys owned by children I need to pick a uniformly distributed (or at least close to uniformly distributed) configuration, that is, a mapping from children to the toys they own.

Generating all the possible configurations and picking j-th is no go — there may be a lot of those.

In the example below there are 4 children: red, blue, green and yellow. Red needs to *own* 4 toys, blue — 5, green — 3, yellow — 3. Toys children *like* are inside the rectangles of corresponding colors.

[image: Children craving for toys]

So what I need is either an outline of an algorithm to generate a well-distributed `Map<Child, Set<Toy>>`, or any links that would be useful to read for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a bipartite graph as follows. For each child `i`, make `t_i` vertices. For each toy `j`, make one vertex. Whenever child `i` likes toy `j`, connect all of `i`'s vertices to `j`'s vertex. The valid assignments of toys to children correspond to perfect matchings in this graph. Compute one assignment using your favorite matching algorithm (e.g., [Hopcroft--Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)) and then run the Markov chain of [Jerrum and Sinclair](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0218077) as long as desired.

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as I will have studied all this, for now have an upvote.

Comment: Could you please expand on how the last two algorithms lead to generating a valid assignment? Ok, so with Hopcroft-Karp we found a singe assignment `A`, and with Jerrum and Sinclair we can roughly find a number `p` of all possible assignments (that is, perfect matchings), if I understand it correctly. Then how do we use `A` and `p` to randomly find one of other valid assignments?

Comment: @Susei Don't count; just use the Markov chain directly. The updated version by [Jerrum--Sinclair--Vigoda](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vigoda/Permanent.pdf) handles sparse graphs.

Comment: So I've finally put enough time in this. It appears to me that a valid assignment of toys to children isn't necessarily a perfect matching in the kind of bigraph you described in your answer. For example, if there are two children, each one needs one toy and likes all of 10 toys they have to choose from. There can't be a perfect matching if a sum of toys needed by children is not equal to number of all toys.

Comment: @Susei Ah. Make an imaginary child who wants the appropriate number of toys and isn't picky about which ones he gets.

Comment: Woah. Such a simple solution, such a quick reply, yet I'd never come up with that myself, I guess. I wish I was decent at math : )

Comment: @Susei It's a trick that's needed semi-frequently on Stack Overflow, when people ask about assignment problems involving differing numbers of things.